# WSO2 ESB iterate mediator together with WSO2DSS gives error cannot find parameter with type:query-param

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am creating WSO2ESB Proxy Service which gets data from WSO2DSS server and iterates throuh it and then sends get requests into WSO2DSS.

```
<iterate id="it"
        expression="//*[local-name()='data']"
        sequential="true">
  <target>
     <sequence>
        <call>
           <endpoint>
              <http method="GET"
                    uri-template="http://localhost:9766/services/TEST/test?testId={uri.var.testId}"/>
           </endpoint>
        </call>
        <send/>
     </sequence>
  </target>
</iterate>
```

But DSS is giving this error:

> [] [2016-11-28 13:13:03,808] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in
>   in-out message receiver
>   {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} DS Code:
>   INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR Nested Exception:-
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in
>   'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param
>   name:testId DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR Source Data
>   Service:- Name: DAKPR Location: /DAKPR.dbs Description: N/A Default
>   Namespace: http://dss.example.com/TEST Current Request Name:
>   test Current Params: {}
>
> at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:354)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:843)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.handleRestRequest(CarbonServlet.java:303)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:152)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The endpoint http://localhost:9766/services/TEST/test?testId=1 is working, however when used with WSO2ESB in iterate mediator it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was solved using this **header** just before call mediator:

```
<header name="Content-Type"  scope="transport" action="remove"/>
```